# console.log running before function execution completes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Expected outcome: Populated array

Actual outcome: Empty array

```
const fs = require('fs');
const logFolder = 'app/logs/';

var timestamps = [];

fs.readdir(logFolder, (err, files) => {
    for (let file of files) {
        let timestamp = parseInt(file.slice(17, -4));
        timestamps.push(timestamp);
    }
});

console.log(timestamps);
```

Comment: `readdir()` is asynchronous, it returns immediately.

Comment: Use `readdirsync()` to run synchronously, or move the `console.log()` to the callbackj function.